# CouchDB with docker-compose not reachable from host (but from localhost)

Tags: docker-compose, couchdb-2.0

I am setting up CouchDB using docker-compose with the following `docker-compose.yml` (the following is a minimal example):

```
version: "3.6"
  services:
    couchdb:
      container_name: couchdb
      image: apache/couchdb:2.2.0
      restart: always
      ports:
      - 5984:5984
      volumes:
      - ./test/couchdb/data:/opt/couchdb/data
      environment:
      - 'COUCHDB_USER=admin'
      - 'COUCHDB_PASSWORD=password'

  couchdb_setup:
    depends_on: ['couchdb']
    container_name: couchdb_setup
    image: apache/couchdb:2.2.0
    command: ['/bin/bash', '-x', '-c', 'cat /usr/local/bin/couchdb_setup.sh | tr -d "\r" | bash']
    volumes:
    - ./scripts/couchdb_setup.sh:/usr/local/bin/couchdb_setup.sh:ro
    environment:
    - 'COUCHDB_USER=admin'
    - 'COUCHDB_PASSWORD=password'
```

The setup script of the second container is executing the script `./scripts/couchdb_setup.sh` that starts with:

```
until curl -f http://couchdb:5984; do
  sleep 1
done
```

Now, the issue is that the `curl` call is always returning `The requested URL returned error: 502 Bad Gateway`. I figured that CouchDB is only listening on `http://localhost:5984` but not on `http://couchdb:5984` as is evident when I bash into the `couchdb` container and issue both curls; for `http://localhost:5984` I get the expected response, for `http://couchdb:5984` as well as `http://<CONTAINER_IP>:5984` (that's `http://192.168.32.2:5984`, in my case) responds with `server 192.168.32.2 is unreachable ...`

I looked into the [configs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/config/intro.html) and especially into the `[chttp]` settings and its `bind_address` argument. By default, `bind_address` is set to `any`, but I have also tried using `0.0.0.0`, to no avail.

I'm looking for hints what I did wrong and for advice how to set up CouchDB with docker-compose. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is probably a Docker issue, not a CouchDB issue.

Comment: Thanks. After more debugging... @Flimzy was right. The `couchdb` network request was routed via the docker engine's proxy. This became evident by 5984 port to 0.0.0.0, which allowed me to access CouchDB from the host via localhost as well as remotely from other machines. Using a proxy server on the host (next to docker) helps with the routing. Lesson learned.